# Transfer a .com domain from wordpress.com to a self hosted website

Tags: wordpress

I think I made a classic mistake: I made a Wordpress.com website, picked a domainname.com and started up my website. After I was trying to add a plugin, I noticed it would cost me around 300$ a year to able to do so (I thought it was free).

I understand now I could use something like "bluehost" to actually host my website, but I was wondering... can I still use the domain.com I chose for my website or will that be lost in the dark forever?

Thanks a lot for your answers to my wordpress-noob-mistake question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom,

If you registered the domain, and have access to the account that renews it, then it's 100% yours and you can point it to load a site from anywhere you want, WordPress.com or any host you choose.

The key is what is called an A DNS record.

This is a record that you set in the domain and instruct it from where, which IP, you want it to point.

In some hosts and setups this is done via a CNAME DNS record but I don't want to confuse you.

Lastly, most hosts have a tutorial of "how to point your domain" or "make your site live" in their service.

Hope this has helped, but let me know!